# Runaway argument? with \def

Tags: parsing, arguments

I have a time value in the format HH:MM (i.e 03:00).

I need to compute the TotalMinutes of this time (expected result 180).

My current code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes}[1]%
  {\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h#1}%
\def\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h#1:#2{\the\numexpr#1*60+#2}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\tOne{03:00}%
\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes{\tOne}\\%
\end{document}
```

but unfortunatelly, it gives me error:

> Runaway argument?
>
> \tOne \\end {document}
>
> ! File ended while scanning use of \timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h.

How to I solve this? What did I misunderstood about argument parsing?

Comment: You have to expand `\tOne` before calling `\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes`. `\expandafter\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes\expandafter{\tOne}` would work. Adding an `\expandafter` to the command definition also works: `\newcommand{\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes}[1]%
  {\expandafter\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h#1}%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your definition, the input

```
\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes{\tOne}
```

gets transformed into

```
\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h\tOne
```

Since the auxiliary macro expects to see

```
<tokens>:<argument>
```

TeX will look for a colon until getting to a `\par` token or the end of the file. The reason is that TeX does *no* macro expansion when collecting arguments to macros.

Thus you need to expand `\tOne` before TeX expands `\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h` and starts looking for its arguments.

Anyhow, there is another fix to do. If you define

```
\newcommand{\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes}[1]%
  {\expandafter\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h#1}
```

then your call will become first

```
\expandafter\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h\tOne
```

and then

```
\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h 03:00
```

The collected arguments will be `03` for `#1` and `0` for `#2`. The second `0` will remain in the input stream and you'll get

```
\the\numexpr#1*60+00
```

which provides the correct result, but by chance. Something like

```
\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes{\tOne}23
```

will surprise you. Better delimiting also the second argument and terminating `\numexpr` with `\relax`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes}[1]{%
  \expandafter\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h#1\@nil
}
\def\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes@h#1:#2\@nil{%
  \the\numexpr#1*60+#2\relax
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\tOne{03:00}%
\timeHHMMToTotalMinutes{\tOne}23

\end{document}
```

This prints 18023. You code, with just `\expandafter` added would print 203.

Comment: Do we have to handle the expansion for a "more than one" argument command in a different way? With the following code, I still get the same error:
\newcommand{\timeStamp}[2]{%{#1-Date (YYYY.MM.DD)}{#2-Time (HH:MM)}
\expandafter\timeStamp@t#1 #2\@nil%}%
\def\timeStamp@t#1.#2.#3 #4:#5\@nil{%
 \the\numexpr#5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365\relax%
}%...\def\tOne{03:00}%\def\dOne{2017.08.01}%\timeStamp{\dOne}{\tOne}\\%

Comment: @JosephMarie It's very difficult to read the code in comments; please ask a followup question.

Comment: Indeed! Here is my new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436868/runaway-argument-with-newcommand2