# Runaway argument? with \newcommand[2]

Tags: parsing, arguments

I have a date (in the format YYYY.MM.DD) and a time (format HH:MM).

From these, I want to compute *a kind of*  TimeStamp/Total of minutes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

% Timestamp
\newcommand{\timeStamp}[2]{%{#1-Date (YYYY.MM.DD)}{#2-Time (HH:MM)}
    \expandafter\timeStamp@t#1 #2\@nil%
}%
\def\timeStamp@t#1.#2.#3 #4:#5\@nil{%
    \the\numexpr#5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365\relax%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\tOne{03:00}%
\def\dOne{2017.08.01}%
\timeStamp{\dOne}{\tOne}\\%
\end{document}
```

> The compiler says: "Runaway argument?"

This is probably due to a problem with the extension of the second argument, because this call (`\timeStamp{\dOne}{03:00}`) is Ok.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\expandafter` only expands one token after the token that follows (unless there are arguments).  In your case this is just `#1`.  One way to get your result, is to collect `#1 #2` expanded in a macro before insertion:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

% Timestamp
\newcommand{\timeStamp}[2]{%{#1-Date (YYYY.MM.DD)}{#2-Time (HH:MM)}
  \edef\mytmp{#1 #2}\expandafter\timeStamp@t\mytmp\@nil%
}%
\def\timeStamp@t#1.#2.#3 #4:#5\@nil{%
    \the\numexpr#5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365\relax%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=2\tracingcommands=2
\def\tOne{03:00}%
\def\dOne{2017.08.01}%
\timeStamp{\dOne}{\tOne}
\end{document}
```

This approach should generalise well to more than two arguments.

Comment: Thx. Clear and concise.

Comment: But not fully expandable.

Comment: Indeed @egreg. I faced this problem in my "real" code, so I switched to a more _complicated_ solution.

Answer (score 6):

One can do some juggling with `\expandafter`, but a direct approach may be better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \joseph_time_stamp:nn
 {
  \__joseph_time_stamp:w #1.#2\q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joseph_time_stamp:nn { ff }
% a devious trick for the colon
\use:x
 {
  \cs_new:Npn
   \exp_not:N \__joseph_time_stamp:w
   ##1.##2.##3.##4\token_to_str:N :##5
   \exp_not:N \q_stop
 }
 {
  \int_eval:n
   {
    #5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\timeStamp}{mm}
 {
  \joseph_time_stamp:ff { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\tOne{03:00}
\def\dOne{2017.08.01}

\timeStamp{\dOne}{\tOne}

\timeStamp{2017.1.1}{0:0} % should print 0

\end{document}
```

If the time specification didn't include the colon, it would be easier; the problem is that `:` is special in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`, so the direct

```
\cs_new:Npn \__joseph_time_stamp:w #1.#2.#3.#4:#5\q_stop
 {
  \int_eval:n
   {
    #5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365
   }
 }
```

would not work and an indirect method is needed in order to “stringify” the colon.

[image]

An expandable solution with `\expandafter` and argument juggling (`OS` for “old style”):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timeStampOS}[2]{%
  \expandafter\timeStampOS@a\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\timeStampOS@a}[2]{%
  \expandafter\timeStampOS@b\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\timeStampOS@b}[2]{\timeStampOS@c #1 #2\@nil}
\def\timeStampOS@c #1.#2.#3 #4:#5\@nil{%
  \the\numexpr
    #5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365
  \relax
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all and excuse me for all. I have added the link for the traslation. +1.

Answer (score 4):

expand #1 *and* #2

```
% Timestamp
\newcommand\timeStamp[2]{%
    \expandafter\timeStamp@t#2 #1\@nil}%
\def\timeStamp@t#1:#2 #3\@nil{\expandafter\timeStamp@@t#3 #1:#2\@nil}%
\def\timeStamp@@t#1.#2.#3 #4:#5\@nil{%
  \the\numexpr#5+#4*60+(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365\relax%
}%
```

Comment: Thx. But now, I am completely confused about '\expandafter'...

Comment: @JosephMarieit expands the first token after the macro after `\expandafter`, there are two tokens here.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearer to:

- devote macros to sub-computations, possibly reusable elsewhere,
- indicate in the macro name the expansion type it does on its arguments.

Like this: (`O` meaning "expands once the argument"; often one would prefer "F" for f-type expansion which expands repeatedly the first token, as this allows nesting. Else one would need e.g. `T` for "expands twice the argument", because  with `\def\foo{\the\numexpr...}`, one needs two expansions for fully expanding).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\TimeStampOO}[2]
   {\the\numexpr\expandafter\DateToMinutes\expandafter{#1}+
                \expandafter\TimeToMinutes\expandafter{#2}\relax}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DateToMinutes}[1]{\the\numexpr\Date@ToMinutes#1\relax}
\def\Date@ToMinutes#1.#2.#3\relax
   {(#3-1)*60*24+(#2-1)*60*24*31+(#1-2017)*60*24*31*365\relax}
\newcommand{\TimeToMinutes}[1]{\the\numexpr\Time@ToMinutes#1\relax}
\def\Time@ToMinutes#1:#2\relax
   {#2+#1*60\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\tOne{03:00}%
\def\dOne{2017.08.01}%
\TimeStampOO{\dOne}{\tOne}%
\end{document}
```

This is expandable.

Comment: the auxiliary macros could use bare `\numexpr`, but with `\the\numexpr` (which adds some overhead in the global computation) they can be used top-level.